# Making a SOAP / XML request from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, rest-client

I have an xml object `xml`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <GetLocations xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1">
                <Request>
                <SourceCredentials>
                    <SourceName>{SourceName}</SourceName>
                    <Password>{Password}</Password>
                    <SiteIDs>
                        <int>{SiteID}</int>
                    </SiteIDs>
                </SourceCredentials>
                <XMLDetail>Bare</XMLDetail>
                <PageSize>10</PageSize>
                <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
                <Fields>
                    <string>Locations.Name</string>
                    <string>Locations.City</string>
                </Fields>
                </Request>
            </GetLocations>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and am trying to copy this request I [found in an example](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/WorkingWithSOAP?version=v5.1):

```
POST https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1/SiteService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1/GetLocations"
Host: clients.mindbodyonline.com
Content-Length: 795
```

But I do not know how to include things like `SOAPAction` in my request using something like `RestClient`.

How do you include such parameters, or is there a different way to make this type of request?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example code they have written in ruby [here](https://github.com/mindbody/API-Examples/tree/master/Ruby).

You can use [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) gem to do the request, you can have a look at this [code](https://github.com/mindbody/API-Examples/blob/master/Ruby/checkout_shopping_cart_example.rb) sample that shows how to do that.

Comment: Due to the fact that I was not able to use savon to make a more complicated request (one involving `xsi:type`) without throwing an error, I wanted to use raw XML

Comment: the example you attached does not seem to work anymore.  It throws an error